# JavaRDD.filter() not working even though JavaRDD.map() works with the function

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have the following function written:

```
Function<LabeledPoint,Boolean> filterPredicateAcc = new Function<LabeledPoint,Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call(LabeledPoint p) {
        List<Double> featureValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double val: p.features().toArray()) {
            featureValues.add(val);
        }
        double pred = finalModel.regressionPrediction(featureNamesList,featureValues);
        int mappedPred = pred >= classOneThreshold ? 1 : 0;
        int label = (int) p.label();

        return mappedPred == label; 
    }
};
```

When I do the following:
JavaRDD data;
data.map(filterPredicateAcc) I get the expected result i.e., a JavaRDD with the correct boolean values.

When I do the following:
data.filter(filterPredicateAcc) it returns null even though some of the elements should be returned.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I need to pass a Boolean function in the filter call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> > > When I do the following: data.filter(filterPredicateAcc) it returns null even though some of the elements should be returned.

Does filterPredicateAcc return a boolean? Also did the map return all boolean values as "False"? In which case the filter returning null makes sense.